# Collect set of objects from nested streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, guava

I have a scenario where I have two for loops, one nested inside the other. In the inner loop, for each iteration, I have the information I need to create a new instance of a particular type. I wanted to change the code from for loops to using streams so I could collect all objects into an ImmutableSet. However, I couldn't make a version which compiles and works. My example program below illustrates my closest attempt. It compiles, but one of the parameters is hardcoded.

How can I fix the stream below so that when I allocate Bar, I have both variables s and n available?

```
class Bar {
  private final String s;
  private final Integer n;

  Bar(String s, Integer n) {
    this.s = s;
    this.n = n;
  }
}

public class Foo {

  private static List<Integer> getList(String s) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(s.hashCode());
  }

  Foo() {
    ImmutableSet<Bar> set = ImmutableSet.of("foo", "bar", "baz")
            .stream()
            .flatMap(s -> getList(s).stream())
            .map(n -> new Bar("", n)) // I need to use s here, not hard-code
            .collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
  }
}
```

Comment: I expect that you would have to use a POJO wrapper class for that, which would be more hassle than just using a regular loop.

Comment: You need to combine the flatMap and the map into a single flatMap. I think that simply means moving one )

Comment: Ah, I could make it work by combining them. I was trying it before posting but made some mistake because it didn't compile. Now it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
.flatMap(s -> getList(s).stream().map(n -> new Bar(s, n)))
```

Simply, chain another `map` operation to `getList(s).stream()` to transform the data, thus enabling you to have both the string and integers in scope.

Note, you're not just limited to `getList(s).stream()`. Meaning one can chain as many complex operations together as they want as long as the function passed to `flatMap` returns a `Stream<R>` it will compile.